# json image in android

Tags: android, json, image

I am new to android. I have to display an image from the json url. I wanted to know wether I can set an image to ImageView without downloading directly from url. Mostly people have done it from sdcard otherwise by downloading it.

Comment: no you cant you have to download the image, if you are lazy enough then can try webview but that will not provide every functionality of Imageview and managing that will result in more work that I hope you dont like

Comment: Thanks ingsaurabh. I think I will try downloading the image

Comment: Is json url different than regular URL? If this is not then do google for searching on "Android - display image from web"

Comment: I have to take these images at runtime. So every time new images will be added I'll have to download them. this may take a lot of time. any other suggestions will also help. thank u

Comment: save them in some directory on SDCARD and before downloading check that directory for images if the images are there then display directly else download them. I will suggest you to search for LazyLoading that will help you in this endeavor

Answer (score 1):

For ImageView you have to download Image or get from sdcard almost you have the image in reference

```
you can not display image directly from the web in ImageView.
```

For this (from url without downloading) purpose I think `you should try WebView` but it doesn't have a all properties as a ImageView.

Comment: I have to take these images at runtime. So every time new images will be added I'll have to download them.  this may take a lot of time. any other suggestions will also help. thank u

Comment: for this purpose you have to download the images but download these images in background use AsyncTask or Thread.